# image Referencing error upon deploy

Tags: c#

Within my Application Bootstrapper I initialize an _taskbarIcon

```
protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>();

    _taskbarIcon = new TaskbarIcon
    {
        Icon = new Icon(AppConfiguration.TaskbarIconRelativePath),
        ToolTipText = AppConfiguration.ApplicationName
    };
}
```

Upon deploying I get this error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll

Additional information: Could not find a part of the path

c:\Users\_____________________\Resources\Images\Icon.ico'.
```

Within my AppConfiguration the constant lies here

```
public static readonly string TaskbarIconRelativePath = "../../Resources/Images/Icon.ico";
```

I'm wondering how should this be deployed. Is there a certain build action I'm suppose to set for the image?

Comment: Is the file at the path in the error message present or not?

Comment: No, windows can't find the file.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to tell; how do you deploy the application? To my understanding, either some deploy action must be defined; alternatively, the icon could be linked as a resource.

Comment: I'm using One Click deployment

Comment: I think it has to do with the relative pathiing. "E:\\Test\\Test.UI.WPF\\bin\\Debug" 

The location of the resources folder is within "E:\\Test\\Test.UI.WPF\\Resources